# Create row including association with hasOne in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm testing different ORM's for Node.js and got stuck at this error:

```
Possibly unhandled TypeError: undefined is not a function
@ person.setUser(user);
```

Tried `person.setUsers`, `user.setPerson` and `user.setPeople`. Also tried console.log to find the function with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.connection, {
    define: {
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscoredAll: true,
        underscored: true
    }
});

var Person = sequelize.define('person', {
    first_name: Sequelize.STRING,
    last_name: Sequelize.STRING
});

var User = sequelize.define('user', {});

Person.hasOne(User);

sequelize.sync().then(run);

function run() {
    var person = Person.create({ first_name: 'Markus', last_name: 'Hedlund' });
    var user = User.create();

    person.setUser(user);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to do is

```
Person.create({ first_name: 'Markus', last_name: 'Hedlund' }).then((person) => {
      User.create().then((user) => {
           person.setUser(user);
      });
});
```

Comment: Of course, that solved it, thanks! :) Wish this was clearer in the docs

Comment: isnt there a way to do with `Person.create({ first_name: 'Markus', last_name: 'Hedlund', {user: { /* data */ }} }` ?

Answer (score 4):

Although dege answer is correct I would write it with a nice promise chain:

```
Person.create({ first_name: 'Markus', last_name: 'Hedlund' })
.bind({})
.then(function(person){
    this.person = person;
    return User.create()
})
.then(function(user){
    return this.person.setUser(user);
});
```